# Closure Compiler update string property name references

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Lets say we have a poll of objects with a function of objects something like below and I want to call each `fn` using something like [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke). We can do this easily before gcc advanced minimization via `_.invoke(pool, "fn"`), no problem. However, after minifcation `fn` may be `c` or some other property name... Is there anyway to **hint** to gcc that a string is referencing a property name? I want it to update my invoke call to `_.invoke(pool, "c")` after it's done minifying the code.

For a reproducible example of the problem try running gcc with advanced compilation on this script:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @externs_url http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/underscorejs
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
var pool = [{fn: function() {}, prop2: 1}, {fn: function() {}, prop2: 2}, {fn: function() {}, prop2: 3}]
_.invoke(pool, "fn");
```

Which produces obviously not equivalent code:

```
_.invoke([{a:function(){},b:1},{a:function(){},b:2},{a:function(){},b:3}],"fn");
```

I'm hoping the resulting compiled code will be

```
_.invoke([{a:function(){},b:1},{a:function(){},b:2},{a:function(){},b:3}],"a");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

1) Quote the original property definition:

```
{"fn": ...}
```

2) Provide a definition in a extern file:

```
/** @type {Object} */
var methods;
methods.fn;
```

3) Use the magic "JSCompiler_renameProperty" method:

```
_.invoke(pool, JSCompiler_renameProperty("fn"));
```

This isn't used much (so has a higher chance of being flaky) and isn't recommended with type based optimizations.  Note that you have a provide a stub implementation like:

```
function JSCompiler_renameProperty(a) { return a; }
```

If you want the code to function uncompiled or compile without warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Just quote the property names you don't want gcc to rename:

```
var pool = [{"fn": function() {}, "prop2": 1}, {"fn": fun ...
```

See also: [inconsistent property names](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames)

Comment: Preferably they would be renamed to a minified name and I could mark the `"fn"` strings as property names. The property name I want to do this to is `targetElement` and shows up throughout my code

Comment: @megawac Yes, I know what you would have wanted to achieve, but I don't think that's possible at all.

Comment: Hmm I'll ask on their irc channel tomorrow and see if theres no better answer :/. Seems dubious given that reference